# Filter Realm with count() in Java

Tags: android, count, aggregate-functions, realm

I'm using latest Realm (0.90.0) and have two RealmObjects Event and Game in one-to-many relationship:

```
public class Event extends RealmObject
{
    ...
    private RealmList<Game> games;
}
```

I wish to filter Events with one of the conditions that count of games must be bigger than 0. I am not sure how to include that filter in my query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `isEmpty`: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#isEmpty-java.lang.String-

e.g

```
RealmResults<Event> results = realm.where(Event.class).not().isEmpty("games").findAll();
```